# Adding private pod to Flutter package

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to get a private Cocoapods repo - Example - set up on the ios side of a Flutter Package I am building - example_plugin.

I created the repo and pushed it, following these [instructions](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html)... `pod search Example` shows:

```bash
 -> Example (0.0.1)
   Example Description
   pod 'Example', '~> 0.0.1'
Homepage: http://github/example
Source:   https://github.com/example.git
Versions: 0.0.1 [Private repo]
```

In the package path `example/ios/example.podspec`, I add:

```rb
s.dependency 'Example', '0.0.1'
  s.source           = {
    :git => "https://github.com/example.git",
    :tag => s.version.to_s
  }
```

However, when I run `pod install` in the project depending on this plugin, I get...

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for Example (= 0.0.1) depended upon by example_plugin
```

It works when I add this in the `example_plugin/example/ios/Podfile`...

```rb
source 'https://github.com/example.git'
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'

pod 'Example', '0.0.1'
```

But I dont see that being done for any of the other packages I currently depend on in my Flutter Application, which tells me that is not the correct way to do it.

My goal is to only have to add:

```yaml
  example_plugin:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/org/example_plugin.git
      branch: master
```

to my project pubspec.yaml and have it connect to the Example pod without additional configuration within the project, as most other dependencies work?

Comment: I fixed the issue and created a PR to add to Flutters documentation.
https://github.com/flutter/website/pull/10251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flutter Docs now outline how to add a Pod to a Flutter package **[here](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#edit-plugin-package:%7E:text=Add%20CocoaPod%20dependencies)**

Credit to [@Aesha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22041698/aesha) for clearing up some confusion around this with a response to this question.

[Ref](https://github.com/flutter/website/pull/10251)

Answer (score 1):

Yes I do, but this is the way i am using in recent project.
Let me explain you in detail

I have used like this in yaml file here is the code:

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter //you need to add this below this line
vpt_engine_plugin:
git:
url: https://github.com/VisualPT/vpt_engine_plugin.git

This is my yaml file looks like and do pod install after adding this then you can directly import in the dart file the package like this

import 'package:vpt_engine_plugin/vpt_engine_plugin.dart';

Be careful for the name you are providing here in yaml file "vpt_engine_plugin:"

Comment: The part that is confusing me is why I dont see it when I run `flutter pub get`. However, it seems to work when I call it in the app that is depending on it, so I guess my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that CocoaPods is unable to find a specification for VPTEngine version 0.0.1, which is a dependency specified by the vpt_engine_plugin. This can happen if the specified version or branch does not exist in the repository or if there is an issue with the CocoaPods repository.

Here are a few things you can check and try:

Check Repository and Version:

1. Make sure that the VPTEngine version 0.0.1 exists in the specified Git repository.

Verify that the branch or tag 0.0.1 exists in the repository. If not, use the correct branch or tag.

2. Update CocoaPods:

Ensure that your CocoaPods is up to date. Run the following commands in your terminal:

gem install cocoapods
pod repo update

3. Specify Commit Hash or Branch:

Instead of specifying a version (0.0.1), try specifying a commit hash or a branch directly in your pubspec.yaml:

dependencies:
vpt_engine_plugin:
git:
url: https://github.com/VisualPT/vpt_engine_plugin.git
ref: master  # Replace with the correct branch or commit hash

4. Check Podspec File:

Verify that the repository contains a proper VPTEngine.podspec file with the correct version information.

5. Double-check the Repository URL:
   Ensure that the URL of the Git repository is correct and accessible.

- After making these adjustments, run flutter pub get again to fetch the dependencies and update the CocoaPods.

Comment: did you just chatgpt this? I tried all of these solutions already...

Comment: yeah look like a ChatGTPt answer. Can you brief which solution is best to solve this issue?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).